# Is there a difference if the Shield is connected to the router or the computer

Tags: arduino

Is there a difference if the Shield is connected to the router or the computer. In fact it is as we obtain Internet access. If there is, how to do better?

Comment: Note the Arduino forum at http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean Ardino Ethernet shield connected to a router, or to a computer?

- Some computers allow that, other computers need a cross-wired ethernet cable. Once the link led lits on the computer, you're ok. Usually "newer" Ethernet cards have Tx/Rx negotiation and work with a straight wired Ethernet cable as well.
- Note that configuring internet sharing (I guess your computer gets internet via wifi or something) requires additional steps
- If your computer is not connected to the Internet (i.e. you want to have a LAN between the Arduino and the computer), then the OS will automatically assign an IP address to the computer. However, you need a DHCP *server* on the computer to automatically assign an IP address to the Arduino.

Considering all of this hassle, you'd better plug in the Ardino to a router.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Most likely I connect to the router.